# TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: on ipad deployment

Tags: xamarin.ios, tinyioc

I'm getting TinyIOC Unable to resolve type exception. I have developed my app using Xamarin studio for ipad. In simulator it is working fine. But on deploying ipad i'm getting below error.

> TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: IOSLoginViewModel ---> System.Exception: Unable to resolve type: IOSLoginViewModel ---> System.Exception: Unable to resolve type:

```cs
private IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> GetTypeConstructors(Type type)
    {
        //#if NETFX_CORE
        //          return type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.OrderByDescending(ctor => ctor.GetParameters().Count());
        //#else
        return type.GetConstructors().OrderByDescending(ctor => ctor.GetParameters().Count());
        //#endif
    }
```

Above method is returning value on simulator but for ipad it is giving null.

Lines of code I have used is

```cs
var tContainer = TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current;
tContainer.Register<IOnlineAuthenticationService, Framework.OnlineProvider.AuthenticationService>().AsMultiInstance(); 


DataContext = TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IOSLoginViewModel>();
```

IOS Build options I have tried all,
Linking - SDK, ALL, No but still same error.

Answer (score 6):

1. In Xamarin Studio, open "Run" -> "Exceptions" and add "System.Exception".
   Run your
2. Run you app
3. When the error occurs, take a look at the exception object's InnerException property which will give you clues why the type could not be resolved.